# Coiled copper wire around 15a power cable for AC

Tags: electrical

Earlier today I noticed my infant son was trying to chew on the power cable for my window unit AC.

I wrapped the lower portion in paracord to try to prevent him from injuring himself.  When I was about halfway through I remembered that one of the strands was made of copper instead of nylon.

This might be a stupid question, but is there any risk of damage or fire?  It's essential a thick gauge power cable tightly coiled with a thin strand of copper:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have there is basically a transformer. There would have to be some voltage induced in the copper conductor, but across only a couple turns of the paracord (the width of an infant's mouth) the voltage would have to be quite minimal because 1) the paracord is wrapped around both hot and neutral so the magnetic field will be near zero and 2) the distance between the paracord and the conductors in the power cord is relatively large. There doesn't appear to be an increase of risk of fire or damage to the power cable on account of the paracord being wound around it.

Unless the infant makes quite a routine of it or bites very hard, I'd guess he's unlikely to pierce the insulation on the power cord anyway.

You could consider treating the cord in some other way if you desired:

- apply something bitter/unpleasant but relatively non-toxic to the cord as a deterrent: soap, or water with a heavy dose of salt or hot pepper powder mixed in
- some other physical protection: make a sheath by splitting a few feet of vinyl tube obtained from a local plumbing store, use split loom tubing, etc
- place furniture, a box, or other object to obstruct/conceal the cord until the child finds interest in teething on some other thing

Comment: Do you think that because the cable has the supply and return insudw then the currents will oppose and cancel? A transformer has current traveling in a single conductor in only one direction...

Comment: @SolarMike Yeah, that's what I'm thinking. Supply and return both running inside the coil looks a lot like the transformer used in a GFCI: only the difference in the two contributes to the voltage induced in the coil. The same idea explains why a clamp-on ammeter must only go around the supply or the return but not both.

Answer (score 1):

See the lumpy socket with the two buttons? **That is a GFCI device**. Its solitary purpose is to protect people from electric shocks related to the device or cord.

If you want to child-safe your home, you should have GFCI devices (of one kind or another) protecting every place there is a chewable cable, except for refrigerators (whose cords are inaccessible anyway).

The child-health problem with GFCI protecting refrigerators is you're trading a *de-minimus* risk of the child pulling the refrigerator out of its alcove to access and chew the cord, for the serious risk of baby-food spoiling because of a GFCI trip.  People are not omniscient, and don't realize when they reset the coffeemaker GFCI the fridge also was out, and food is now questionable. This is particularly a risk for persons served food by other persons (who don't eat that food themselves).